# What's a fast/clean way to print HTML in PHP without breaking tags?

Tags: php, html

I have a string with HTML content within.

```
$html = "<p>Some info</p><p>Some other info</p><p>more info</p>...";
```

I would like to print out the first 500 or so characters. Unfortunately, `$html` is not consistent enough to do:

```
$html = substr($html, 0, 500);
```

This could result in broken / open HTML tags, which would then destroy the layout of my page.

I *could* do something like the following:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

and just grab the first three paragraphs, which would be "close enough" to the 500 characters I need, but there's always outliers that make this method unappealing. Additionally, `$html` isn't proper HTML, so it'll throw warnings all over the place.

#### My question can be condensed to the following:

How can I print out 500 characters of HTML content without breaking the layout or structure of the HTML (both within the `$html` variable, and the actual page it's being outputted on)?

Comment: Are you trying to create excerpt for your article? If yes you should look how wordpress implemented it.

Comment: I'm trying to add a paywall, which should be pretty similar to an excerpt from a coding perspective.

Comment: I would try to split text into a words and root level text. Meaning in your example it would be `['<p>Some info</p>','<p>Some other info</p>','<p>more info</p>','notice', 'text', 'is', 'split', 'by', 'word']` this way you can safely count needed characters without breaking actual html. But still this approach depends on your parsing algorythm

Comment: There's no parsing currently going on. I'm working with legacy code that pulls an article, HTML included, from the DB. It just prints exactly that article, and was made pre-Wordpress, so nothing fancy's going on. I need to parse out a snippet so that we can have a well-styled paywall for premium articles.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PHP solution, but might be a good alternative to what you're trying to do. If it's not, then just kindly ignore it.

CSS has text-overflow that renders a "..." for text that goes pass it's container element. Here's some info on it: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Maybe it's an easier solution than custom parsing HTML code, depends on what exactly you're trying to do of course.

Comment: I need the content to explicitly not show, since this _is_ a paywall.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the HTML and only care about the text content within, you should just `strip_tags()` then grab 500 characters worth of text.

Comment: I do care about the HTML.